# Is a subset of an inner product space also an inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

My question may seem trivial but it's important that I know this. I know for a fact that a sub*space* of an inner product space is also an inner product space, but how about an arbitrary sub*set*? Could I argue that since we are allowed to pick any subset, we could pick one that is not a subspace and since it is not a subspace it is not eligible as an inner product space?

Thank you!

Comment: of course you can choose any subset, so also one that is not a subspace.

Comment: Unless you're talking about the trivial vector space $\{0\}$ which has only the additive identity vector of the underlying field, in which case any nonempty subset is actually a subspace.

Comment: A small note: you should actually present a subset that is not a *vector* space, for it can fail to be vector *sub*-space yet still admit a vector space structure, or even inner product space. Anyhow, this inner product space would never be a sub inner product space, which is what you're interested in (I believe, correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subset of an inner product space does not have to be an inner product space.

As you said, we can pick a subset that is not a subspace, hence not an inner product space.

Answer (score 1):

An inner product space is by definition a vector space. Therefore, if a subset is not a subspace, then it cannot be an inner product space.

You can still talk about many properties that you might be interested in, such as perpendicularity and so forth.

For instance, you could take a subset $S$ of an inner product space $H$, and examine $\langle x,y \rangle$ for $x,y \in S$. For a subset of $S'$ you could also define $$(S')^\perp = \{ x \in S : \langle x,y \rangle =0 \text{ for all } y \in S\},$$ however $(S')^\perp$ would not necessarily be a subspace either.